# Print current expected path on error

Tags: rust

Rust newbie here. I am trying to open a file with:

```
let file = File::open("file.txt").unwrap();
```

Due to my build setup it looks like my binary and txt are not where I expect it to be or I am doing something wrong so I am getting a:

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { repr: Os { code: 2, message: "No such file or directory" } }', ../src/libcore/result.rs:736
```

The error message does not say anything about what the expected path where the txt has to live should be so that my program and tests see it. How can I print this expected path? I would like to print a message like:

```
The file "/expected/folder/file.txt" does not exist
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just match returned `Result` explicitly against required error like this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::ErrorKind;

fn main() {
    match File::open("file.txt") {
        Ok(file) => 
            println!("The file is of {} bytes", file.metadata().unwrap().len()),
        Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::NotFound =>
            println!("The file {}/file.txt does not exist", std::env::current_dir().unwrap().display()),
        Err(e) => 
            panic!("unexpected error: {:?}", e),
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c84b288df1cf04544c5c&version=stable)

Comment: I can't find the original Rust issue with a minute or two of searching, but it was argued if the file error types should include the path or not. If I recall correctly, it was decided that they should not include the path, as it would be more overhead than it is worth. As shown, you can always add the path information yourself.